# Reset inputs after submit click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks in advance for your help! I am asking users questions, and giving them input back. I want them to be able to do it again if they want, so i guess i want a reset button. I want to reset the input boxes, after the user hits submit. I have seen some really good answers to this question, but i would like to see a working example, after submit is clicked. It don't matter to me how i do it, if it's a href link that brings them to a sub domain and then back to the original one.  Or if i make the  input val "". My fiddle has some issues, I cut it apart quickly just so i can give a example of what i am trying to do. My input's come from a change function. My fiddle is below. If you pick the first option which is  "Yes" it will work. Please if you can show a working example it will be very helpful.

```
$('.myOptions').change(function () {
$('.list').removeClass('active');
$('.' + this.value).addClass('active');
});


$('#butt').click(function () {
var ttta = $('.myOptions').val();
var tt = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
});
```

My html code:

```
<label>Please select an option :</label>
<select class="myOptions">
<option value="" selected>Pick an option</option>
<option value="owner">yes</option>
<option value="not-owner">no</option>

</select>
```

My fiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/46tYs/8/

Comment: Doesn't the standard HTML `<input type="reset">` work?

Comment: @Barmar it probably will work, I have tried everything I seen and could not get it to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `input[type="reset"]`:

```
<input type='reset' id='reset' value='reset' />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46tYs/11/

Answer (score 2):

With your example I simply cleared the `inputs` and reset the `select`

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
    $("select").val("").change();
    $("input").val("");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/46tYs/9/)

Comment: just tried it, not working. If I select yes again the numbers are still there.

Comment: @Phil Famme have you really tried. I m go through it working perfectly.Please try again

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("select").val("")`? This assumes all the menus use an empty value as their default.

Comment: The problem is if i hit reset and then go back to do it again it still has all of the input values.